# How to POST data from client to node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am trying to POST the data from a form using a function to node.js server to be inserted into SQLITE. But somehow the data is not posted to the node.js server at all. These are what I have done:

**client.js**

```js
//function triggered when submit button is clicked
function createInvitation() {
    var id = localStorage.getItem('id');
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var refno = Math.floor(Math.random()*89999999+10000000);
    //i got all the data here
    alert(id + name + phone + email + refno)
    
    if (name == "" || phone == "" || email == "")
        {
            alert("Please fill in all details!");
        }
    else {
        $.post('/visitors',
        {
            host_id: id,
            visitor_name: name,
            visitor_phone: phone,
            visitor_email: email,
            reference_no: refno
        },
            function(data) {
            alert(data);
                window.location.reload();
        });
    }
}
```

**server.js**

```js
app.post('/visitors', function(request,response){
    console.log('POST request received at /visitors');
    var sql = 'INSERT INTO visitors(host_id, visitor_name, visitor_phone, visitor_email, reference_no) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
    var visitors = [request.body.host_id, request.body.visitor_name, request.body.visitor_phone, request.body.visitor_email, request.body.reference_no];
    console.log(visitors);
    db.run(sql, visitors, function(err) {
        
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error: "+err);
        }
        else {
            response.status(200).redirect('generate.html');
        }
    });
});
```

Any advises will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

---

UPDATE:
[Is this correct?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP0Qe.png)

Comment: Can you check if you are using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))` in your server.js file? if not..please add and run. The form is sending data in formData and not in JSON maybe that is the issue.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal yes, I'm already using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));`

Comment: hmm... can you check in chrome inspect as to what data or in which format the data is being sent to the API? and update it in question...screenshot will be helpful.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal i've updated the post with picture. But I'm not sure if that's the one that you actually want. I apologise for that as I'm still a beginner in web dev

Comment: Hey .. Do 1 thing... check `preserve log` in google console and show me the result/response and request of the API which your are calling. It's the final redirected page and not the one which can give me more details...